# Floating-point exception handlers which does more than diagnostic and abort

Tags: exception, floating-point, x86

Are there any examples of the non-trivial floating point exception handlers ?  By non-trivial I mean a code which does more than just report the error and terminate the program.  For instance, detecting the step which caused underflow and aborting only the leaf, or correcting the source data, whatever.

Or does all numerical software runs with underflow/denormal exceptions handled in hardware ?  While researching the question, I did not found any code, but did read the following article http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1788/email/pdfmPSi1DgZZf.pdf which explains why the option of handling the exceptions is not popular.  Still, if hardware handles it, software could as well, at least on x86.

I am looking for the consumers of SIGFPE and ucontext_t interfaces, I am not writing the handler myself.